# Howto log to syslog in bash script in cygwin?

Tags: bash, logging, cygwin

How do I log messages to syslog using a bash script in cygwin?  In a standard linux disto, I can use a logger(1) utility, but I cannot seem to find that utility in cygwin anywhere.  I've installed the syslog-ng package, but still cannot seem to find the utility anywhere.

Am I missing something somewhere?  Is this even feasible from within a cygwin bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try
[`util-linux`](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/util-linux/)
package.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about adhering to the syslog protocol you can always just send the message directly to the syslog port with nc:

```
echo "Some message" | nc localhost 514
```

Syslog-ng will be nice about logging your message to some reasonable default destination even though there is no syslog header.

If you need to specify facility or severity you could craft a syslog header yourself. The format isn't very complicated: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424